# Good way to check for duplicates and remove them from a DataTable, against a database table?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce-4

I have a populated DataTable in my code:

I'm using SQL Server CE 4.0 and to get around performance issues, I'm using `SqlCeBulkCopy`:

```
SqlCeBulkCopyOptions options = new SqlCeBulkCopyOptions();
options = options |= SqlCeBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls;

// Check for DB duplicates
using (SqlCeBulkCopy bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(strConn, options))
{
    dt = RemoveDuplicateRows(dt, "Email");
    bc.DestinationTableName = "Recipients";
    bc.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

`RemoveDuplicateRows` will remove duplicates from the DataTable, but there is no check against what already exists in the database.

I want to efficiently remove all items in the DataTable that exist in the actual database table, prior to passing it to `WriteToServer(dt)`.

What would be a good performance, cost effective solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So you need to marge datatable and existing table right?  I am not sure if sql ce supports temp table, I did something simular with ms sql, here is pseudo-code

```
string tmpTableDefinition = "create table #tmpEmails (...)";
using(var connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
{
    //Create temp table
    var tmpTableCommand = new SqlCeCommand(tmpTableDefiniton, connection);
    tmpTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Bulk copy to the temp table, note that bulk copy run faster if the teble is empty
    //which is always true in this case...
    using (var bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(connection, options))
    {
         bc.DestinationTableName = "#tmpEmails";
         bc.WriteToServer(dt);
    }
    //Run a sp, that have temp table and original one, and marge as you wish in sql
    //for sp to compile properly, you would have to copy tmp table to script too
    var spCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_MargeTempEmailsWithOriginal", connection);
    spCommand.Type = SP //Don't remember exact prop name and enum value
    spCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```